# ElasticSearch date/time mapping

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

This is my input data:

```
"INC_Cancelled_Date_Time": "2017-05-19 07:26:34"
```

This is my mapping:

```
"INC_Cancelled_Date_Time":{
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
   }
```

This is my error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse [INC_Cancelled_Date_Time]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse [INC_Cancelled_Date_Time]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Invalid format: \"19-05-2017 07:26:34\" is malformed at \"17 07:26:34\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I have altered the format to dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss and gotten no-where. Fiddled around a lot. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Hey, can you confirm what version of the Elastic Stack you are using?

Comment: Yes. Using the latest download from the website - 5.4.0

Comment: It seems like you actually insert 19-05-2017 instead 2017-05-19